# Renovate does not find private dependencies

Tags: renovate

I hosted Renovate, Gitea and Artifactory myself.
Unfortunately, Renovate returns the following warnings:

```
WARN: Package lookup failures (repository=my_repository, branch=renovate.my_branch)
       "warnings": [
         "Failed to look up maven package my_group:my_artifactid",
         ...
```

My Renovate configuration:

```
{
  "platform": "gitea",
  "endpoint": "https://mygitea/api/v1/",
  "token": "my_gitea_token",
  "branchPrefix": "renovate.",
  "logFile": "/mydir/renovate.log",
  "logFileLevel": "debug",
  "extends": [ "config:base"],
  "hostRules": [
    {
      "matchHost": "my_artifactory_repo_url",
      "username": "my_artifactory_user",
      "password": "my_artifactory_password"
    }
  ],
  "repositories": [
    "my_repository"
  ]
}
```

Private dependencies are not found, only the public ones.
What could be the problem?

I have used the following documentation: https://docs.renovatebot.com/getting-started/private-packages/#dependency-version-lookups

Comment: You have specified the ```hostType``` as ```maven``` and provided the ```matchHost```, ```username```, and ```password``` for your private Artifactory repository. However, it's not clear if you've specified the ```hostType``` correctly. The ```hostType``` should match the type of the package manager you're using. If you're using Maven for your Java project, then ```maven``` would be the correct ```hostType```.

Comment: @KeyboardCorporation Same warning with hostType maven. From renovate documentation: "You usually don't need to configure it in a host rule if you have already configured matchHost and only one host type is in use for those, as is usually the case."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use your private registry by default for all Maven dependencies, you can use the following Renovate configuration:

```json
{
  "packageRules": [
    {
      "matchDatasources": ["maven"],
      "registryUrls": [
        "https://artifactory.mycompany.net/artifactory/maven-repo"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: How is this to be configured if there are also npm packages in my Artifactory in addition to maven?

Comment: Add another rule and change the `matchDatasource` and `registryUrls` accordingly.